# Get description value instead of code value on jsf page

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have a view object which has an attribute. This attribute has an LOV which maps a description and code. When the user on the front page selects from this LOV the front end of course displays the nice user description text, but the value stored is the code. This is expected. I would now like to extract the description text so I can pass it as a parameter to another page. So if I set a property listener and set the parameter as `from="#{binding.myview.myattribute}" to="#{pageFlowScope.myParam}"` the param gets set with the code, but I would like to set it as the description instead. How can I do this?

Comment: **You** populate the description  and I would assume this is based on t gharge code, so you could daily retrieve it again.

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry I am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your LOV the description attribute has the index i, Use #{binding.myview.myattribute.selectedValue.attributeValues[i]} instead.